# ExtJS data store don't work with short name model

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I have this code:

```
Ext.define('Operations.view.main.menu.MainMenuModel', {

    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.mainmenu',

    requires: [
        'Ext.data.TreeStore',
        'Operations.data.schema.TreeSchema',
        'Operations.model.MainMenu'
    ],

    schema: 'tree',

    stores: {
        mainMenuStore: {
            type: 'tree',
            model: 'MainMenu',
            root: {
                expanded: true,
                children: [{
                    text: 'Operations',
                    iconCls: 'x-fa fa-home',
                    leaf: true
                }]
            }
        }
    }
});
```

It doesnt work.

If I change `model: 'MainMenu',` to `model: 'Operations.model.MainMenu',` it works! Mystic! Why it happens? Why does he require you to specify the full name? This is the only place I have where it happens.

I use `Sencha ExtJS 6.0.2 Classic`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Models do not support aliases, so you need to specify the full name.

---

Aliases are written in the format *namespace.name*.
Supported namespaces are (the documentation is very vague on this, so there could be more):

- feature
- plugin
- store
- widget
- controller
- viewmodel